# How to convert list of string from scenario outline to object

Tags: java, cucumber

Is there a way to convert a list of string from scenario outline into an Object, for example :

```
Scenario Outline: eligibility rules
    When I specify habitation details
      | <you_are> | <nature> | <pro> |

 Examples:
      | you_are| nature | pro |
      | PNO | Living | No |
      | PO | Pro | yes |
```

Into :

```
class Entry {
   String you_are;
   String nature;
   String pro ;
}

@When("I specify habitation details")
    public void specifyHabitationDetails(Entry entry) {
```

I know you can pass a list of Object using datatable but that is not what I want. The advantage of scenario outline is that each line is repetead from a clean state.

Comment: Why do you need to convert here? Cucumber uses REGEX to identify these test cases, from that you can build a class within the test; I don't think the way you're trying to do it is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse the login of DataTable for ScenarioOutline examples. Each line in the examples table will be as you said a clean slate.

Modify your feature and step definition to use a DataTable. The header should match the variable names in your Entry class for Cucumber to automatically create the object, also provide the 3 arg constructor in the Entry class.

```
When I specify habitation details
 | you_are   | nature   | pro   |
 | <you_are> | <nature> | <pro> |
```

Examples portion remains the same...

```
@When("I specify habitation details")
    public void specifyHabitationDetails(List<Entry> entry) {

          Entry e = entry.get(0);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this works !
The only problem is that I get a List<Entry> with one element. I must then entry.get(0) to get my object.
Is there a way to get directly the actual Object  ? There always must be only one Object is the List.

Comment: By default DataTable looks for multiple rows of data. If you directly want the Entry object try a bit off a hack with a delimited string passed to the step in the feature file. --  When I specify habitation details <you_are>@<nature>@<pro>. Modify your stepDefinition -- public void specifyHabitationDetails(Entry entry). Create a single argument constructor in Entry class with the delimited string as argument. Place the logic to initialize the variables. Cucumber will automatically call this constructor and give you the Entry object.